# What is the point of the flag for questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, declined-flags

I flagged a question for moderator attention on Stack Overflow as it wasn't a question - it was just a post about how to do something. This was declined with the reason:

> please use the standard close reasons to close questions, rather than the 'requires moderator attention' flags

So what is the point of the flag on questions?

Comment: What question is this about? From that message, it seems there's a close-vote reason that would've been a better fit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966858/external-css-in-stack-snippets-takes-priority-over-internal-css-solved - at the time there wasn't a close vote other than other with your own thing or a flag with other and your own thing and I thought a flag was better as you weren't able to vote to delete it like you can now too

Comment: That's a tutorial, which can be closed as _"unclear what you're asking"_.

Comment: But they weren't asking anything so it's not *unclear what they are asking*, it simply isn't a question?

Comment: @Pete and what does pinging a moderator do in regards to that? Honestly, if the question deserves closure, all you need is a close vote. You can always make your own reason as you close it. There was no benefit in involving a moderator here.

Comment: @Patrice, at the time I thought if you flag it, then a moderator would delete it.  Since then, they seem to have added that once you close a question, you can now vote to delete it - not sure if this is a new feature or something I have unlocked as my rep has got higher

Comment: You can vote to delete a closed question once you have 10k rep so long as it's been closed for 2 days. At 20k rep, you can delete vote as soon as it's closed so long as it has a score of -3 or lower.

Comment: Ah ok, think I must have hit 20k after that then as I've never seen a closed question after 2 days

Comment: *it's not unclear what they are asking, it simply isn't a question?* - I believe the thought process goes like this: "If a question post doesn't contain an a clear question, then it is unclear what the OP is asking. I can't find a question in this question post. Therefore, it is unclear what the OP is asking." Whether the OP intended to ask a question doesn't enter into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is for issues that cannot be resolved without moderator involvement.  A non-exhaustive list of things that the community cannot handle, and that would merit a moderator flag are:

- an edit war on the post, possibly because the author is trying to vandalize their own content
- suspicious voting patterns that may be the result of voting fraud
- a question needing to be marked as Community Wiki

If, however, you feel a question should be closed, deleted, is spam, is offensive, etc. then you should use the specific flags set up precisely for those issues, as they can resolve the problem without requiring moderator involvement.

Answer (score 3):

Those flags are for issues that the community cannot handle. Closing an off-topic question can be handled by the community.

However, things like (but not limited to) reporting that a revision needs removed due to confidential information, reporting a record of abuse by a user, or reporting something else that the mods *should* handle but you can't flag otherwise can use this flag. Yes, these issues should be few and far between, but they do happen on occasion.

Even if you could not close vote, there are standard flags for question closure. Those flags and votes put the question into the close vote queue for *the community* to handle. Moderators are meant to be exception handlers. Only flag *"in need of moderator attention"* if a moderator, not community members, needs to handle the situation.